# How is Inventor's Apprentice affected by multiple artifacts?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have 3 artifacts and 1 [Inventor's Apprentice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInventor%27s%5d%2b%5bApprentice%5d). Does my apprentice get +1/+1 or +3/+3?

Answer (score 10):

Inventor's Apprentice gets +1/+1 as long as you control an artifact. It's only +1/+1, and this is true no matter how many artifacts you control. If it was the other way, it would say "Inventor's Apprentice gets +1/+1 for each artifact you control", as it does for [Cranial Plating](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCranial%20Plating%5d).

Comment: Thanks.  I was pretty sure that was the case, I was just reminding myself.